# failure to install ocaml-top on mac

Tags: ocaml

I'm attempting to install ocaml-top on a mac but receiving the following failure message. Any idea? Thanks!

I tried:

`opam install ocaml-top`

And received the following

```
  `∗ install ocaml-top 1.1.5

<><> Gathering sources ><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>   
[ocaml-top.1.1.5] found in cache

<><> Processing actions <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>   
[ERROR] The compilation of ocaml-top failed at
        "/Users/danielfriedman/.opam/opam-init/hooks/sandbox.sh build jbuilder
        build -p ocaml-top".

#=== ERROR while compiling ocaml-top.1.1.5 ====================================#
# context     2.0.2 | macos/x86_64 | ocaml-base-compiler.4.06.1 | https://opam.ocaml.org#866ea725
# path        ~/.opam/4.06.1/.opam-switch/build/ocaml-top.1.1.5
# command     ~/.opam/opam-init/hooks/sandbox.sh build jbuilder build -p ocaml-top
# exit-code   1
# env-file    ~/.opam/log/ocaml-top-49246-ffb3fd.env
# output-file ~/.opam/log/ocaml-top-49246-ffb3fd.out
### output ###
#     ocamlopt src/.main.eobjs/completion.{cmx,o} (exit 2)
# (cd _build/default && /Users/danielfriedman/.opam/4.06.1/bin/ocamlopt.opt -w -40 -g -I src/.main.eobjs -I /Users/danielfriedman/.opam/4.06.1/lib/bytes -I /Users/danielfriedman/.opam/4.06.1/lib/lablgtk2 -I /Users/danielfriedman/.opam/4.06.1/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs -I /Users/danielfriedman/.opam/4.06.1/lib/ocaml/threads -I /Users/danielfriedman/.opam/4.06.1/lib/ocp-indent/lexer -I /Users/daniel[...]
# File "src/completion.ml", line 39, characters 4-26:
# Error: Unbound value IndexScope.read_string



<><> Error report <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>   
┌─ The following actions failed
│ λ build ocaml-top 1.1.5
└─ 
╶─ No changes have been performed`
```

Comment: This is just a bug, and you should submit a report to the package issue tracker: https://github.com/OCamlPro/ocaml-top/issues